# CodeSchool: Rails Best Practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys I wanted to know if anyone has purchased [this Rails course](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-best-practices) and what you think of it?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm fairly new at rails and I'm still trying to wrap my ahead around certain things.

Any other advice regarding where to find active blog posts about rails would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in a similar position, though have not purchased the rails course you linked.
That said [This Book (Agile Web Development with Rails)](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) has been a godsend - and many others in the rails community have said this is the 'go-to' book so I'd suggest giving it a look :)

Comment: I've gone through this book as well, but I got stuck when you had to send emails because it doesn't seem to work locally :(

Answer (score 1):

Iv'e Completed most of the courses at codeschool to date.  They are all pretty good to excellent.  Especially the rails & ruby courses. Good for beginners & go into good depth too. Can't recommend them enough.   Definitely worth the money.  Subscribe, its $20 a month if you complete a course.   No i don't work for them. : )

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend taking a look at Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/).  The book is online for free, updated frequently, and the related paid screencasts are well worth the money.  It won't just teach you Rails best practices, but also best practices *as a developer* using Ruby on Rails to craft web apps (eg Test-Driven Development, version control, deployment etc).  I love the [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) book mentioned (it was my intro to Rails, too) but I believe I got more value out of Rails Tutorial.

**Edit**: I should probably add that Code School are awesome and I have done the course mentioned by @imjp.  I thought it was worth the money, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of purchasing it, you could just subscribe to their newsletter,
Due to the fact that their service is new, they offer all the courses FOR FREE very often. 
It's a great course for ruby newbies, and a great site overall!